# One-Way data binding of a DataGridView to list of objects

Tags: c#, sorting, data-binding, datagridview, filtering

I know there are many similar questions and I spent a lot of time looking at possible solutions. But I'm still not sure what's the easiest way to do it.

The goal is to show `LogItems` (timestamp, severity level, message) in a `DataGridView` sorted by their timestamp and allowing the user to filter the items by severity level.

Here is exactly what I (don't) need:

- One-way data binding of a `DataGridView` to a list/collection of objects. No need to edit the objects via `DataGridView` or to add/remove objects via `DataGridView` by the user. But the `DataGridView` should automatically update when I add or remove objects to that underlying list/collection.
- The objects have a timestamp (`DateTime`) and should be displayed ordered by this timestamp. I don't care if the list itself keeps them sorted (something like `SortedList<T>` would be nice, but it doesn't exist) or if the `DataGridView` or a `BindingSource` takes care of the sorting. No need for the user to set up sorting by clicking on the column headers.
- Simple filtering based on the value of a single column (severity).

Here some approaches I came up with:

- Use a `BindingList<T>` as the underlying collection doesn't work since it doesn't support sorting and filtering.
- Wrapping some collection with a `BindingSource` doesn't help if the underlying collection doesn't support sorting and filtering.
- Write a custom collection which implements `IBindingListView`. This looks quite complicated and I need only a subset of the features that `IBindingListView` provides. And I'm too lazy.
- Use the `BindingListView` [sourceforge project](http://blw.sourceforge.net/). This is probably too heavy for what I need and I don't want to rely on third party libraries if I don't have to.

What would be a simple and fast solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `DataTable` would be an option, but in the end I decided to use the `BindingListView` from [sourceforge](http://blw.sourceforge.net/) instead and I'm very happy with it.

The problem with the `DataTable` approach is that it would require to copy all the data from my custom objects into a `DataTable` just for displaying.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use a DataTable. You'll get all you need.

Just make the DataGridView ReadOnly to prevent user editing. it will still update when the underlying DataTable is updated.

Cheers